# Run linux command in python 3

Tags: python, bash, python-3.5, gimp, gimpfu

Running the following command in linux bash succeeds:

```
gimp --no-interface -b '(python-fu-scale RUN-NONINTERACTIVE 0 0 "img.jpg")' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'
```

Output:

```
batch command executed successfully
```

is printed and child process exits

Running it with python3.5 fails:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("gimp --no-interface -b '(python-fu-scale RUN-NONINTERACTIVE 0 0 \"img.jpg\")' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'".split())
```

results in output:

```
batch command executed successfully
batch command executed successfully
```

and the child process is stuck.

I'm not sure what's the difference and how to achieve equivalent behaviour in python.
Is there a way to run bash command as string?

Comment: Try `subprocess.run("gimp --no-interface -b".split() + ['(python-fu-scale RUN-NONINTERACTIVE 0 0 \"img.jpg\")', '-b', '(gimp-quit 0)'])`

Comment: Just in case it matters, Gimp scripts only run with Python 2.7.

Comment: thanks a lot, if i got u right. my script runs with python3, but _python-fu-scale_ runs with python 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following source - [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python?rq=1)   helped to find an answer

```
import subprocess
import shlex
subprocess.run(shlex.split("gimp --no-interface -b '(python-fu-scale RUN-NONINTERACTIVE 0 0 \"img.jpg\")' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'"))
```

Comment: Dude you helped me so much with this.